# How to run get the result from a query built from SELECT FORMAT in Postgresql at pgadmin?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, pgadmin

I have a command to run in pgadmin which looks like below:

```
SELECT format('SELECT * FROM %I.%I CROSS JOIN LATERAL json_to_record(%I::json) AS rs(%s)', 'public', 'vehicles', 'column_A', array_to_string(
               (SELECT ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT col FROM vehicles CROSS JOIN LATERAL json_object_keys(column_A::json) AS t(col) ORDER BY col)), ' text , '
 ) || ' text')
```

It prints a string starting with  `SELECT` statement.

How do I get the result from the query straight from the string returned by the `FORMAT`?

I have tried something like:

```
DO
$$

WITH str as( SELECT format('SELECT * FROM %I.%I CROSS JOIN LATERAL json_to_record(%I::json) AS rs(%s)', 'public', 'vehicles', 'column_A', array_to_string(
               (SELECT ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT col FROM vehicles CROSS JOIN LATERAL json_object_keys(column_A::json) AS t(col) ORDER BY col)), ' text , '
 ) || ' text'))

BEGIN EXECUTE str;

END
$$
```

However, I got an error message saying:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WITH"

<s>What have I missed here? Please advise!!</s>

## Updated answer

After combining answers from the experts below, here is the updated version for future reference:

```
do $$
DECLARE
   query text;
begin
    query := format('SELECT * FROM %I.%I CROSS JOIN LATERAL json_to_record(%I::json) AS rs(%s)', 'public', 'vehicles', 'column_A', array_to_string(
               (SELECT ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT col FROM vehicles CROSS JOIN LATERAL json_object_keys(column_A::json) AS t(col) ORDER BY col)), ' text , '
 ) || ' text');
    execute format('create or replace temp view tmp_view_vehicles as %s', query);
end $$;

select * from tmp_view_vehicles;
```

Thank you everyone & your patience!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to create the stored function but want to get the result using anonymous `do` block then you could to use temporary view:

```
do $$
begin
    execute format('create or replace temp view tmp_view_123 as select ...', ...);
end $$;

select * from tmp_view_123;
```

Created view is visible for the current session only.

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a974e402eed29f62e0d4d06868a8e5fa)

Comment: Very very useful suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing up SQL and PL/pgSQL syntax, and not in a very consistent fashion.

Define a PL/pgSQL variable:

```
DO
$$DECLARE
   query text;
   result record;
BEGIN
   query := format(...);
   EXECUTE query INTO result;
END;$$;
```

Comment: how do I get the result from the `EXECUTE query`?

Comment: `EXECUTE ... INTO`. But that is not connected to your question, is it?

Comment: Sorry if I have not made my question clear. I want to get the result built from the string query. In other words, I want to get the result from the `format(...)`, which is a `Select` statement. How do I use `EXECUTE ... INTO` to get the result from the `Select`?

Comment: Do you want to get the `SELECT` statement or the result from the `SELECT` statement? The former is in `query`, the latter can be had with `EXECUTE query INTO var`.

Comment: I have updated my question. I want to get the result from the `SELECT` statement. Can you update the answer with `EXECUTE query INTO var`? How do I declare the `var` type above?

Comment: Ok, done. But that's the end of the tutorial session. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The plain answer is

```sql
do language plpgsql
$$
begin
 EXECUTE format('SELECT ....' <your code here>);
end;
$$;
```

However anonymous blocks do not return anything. Maybe you'll have to shape the block as a [table-returning function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084936/pl-pgsql-functions-how-to-return-a-normal-table-with-multiple-columns-using-an).

- **Edit**

I do not think that there is a straightforward way to do this - change the return table structure of a function dynamically. But you *can* return a single json column with key-value pairs inside.
Here is such a function:

```sql
create or replace function query_to_jsonset(qr text) returns setof json as
$$
begin
    return query execute 'SELECT row_to_json(dyntbl) FROM ('||qr||') AS dyntbl';
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

and then your query will look simple as that:

```sql
select js from query_to_jsonset(format(....)) js;
```

Please note that `query_to_jsonset` is unsafe.

Comment: how do I return a table of undefined columns?