# Struggling to create function in Postgres on pgADmin4

Tags: postgresql

I am very new to Postsgres development and am struggling to create a function
to return a Select statement

My code is as follows:

```
create function getdevices() returns table as $$
begin
   SELECT
                DeviceID,
                SerialNumber,
                ProductCode,
                Description,
                SoftwareVersion,
                Build,
                BuildDate,
                Assigned,
                GroupID,
                DeviceConnectionIndex       
            FROM dbo.Device;
end;
$$;
```

When i try to run this by pressing F5, I get the following error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "as"
LINE 1: create function getdevices() returns table as $$
                                                   ^ 

SQL state: 42601
Character: 44
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you have to define the columns names and types there see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084936/pl-pgsql-functions-how-to-return-a-normal-table-with-multiple-columns-using-an

Comment: You probably should create a `VIEW` for that purpose, not a function

Comment: `language` is also missing, just like the language you want to use. Please check the manual for the correct and complete syntax. Use the examples in the manual, and change them slightly to get the result you need.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is found here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html

Specifically the returns table line should be written as follows:

```
RETURNS TABLE ( column_name column_type [, ...] )
```

So you'll need to specify the name and types of the selected columns:

DeviceID,
SerialNumber,
ProductCode,
Description,
SoftwareVersion,
Build,
BuildDate,
Assigned,
GroupID,
DeviceConnectionIndex

Assuming everything is an 'int' (probably won't be) then this would work. The 'begin' and 'end' is not needed unless you are doing something needing PL-SQL e.g. looping to generate parameters. You also need to specify the language as one comment suggests:

```
 create or replace function getdevices() 
 returns table (DeviceID int,
       SerialNumber int,
            ProductCode int,
            Description int,
            SoftwareVersion int,
            Build int,
            BuildDate int,
            Assigned int,
            GroupID int,
            DeviceConnectionIndex int) as $$
            
SELECT
     DeviceID,
     SerialNumber,
     ProductCode,
     Description,
     SoftwareVersion,
     Build,
     BuildDate,
     Assigned,
     GroupID,
     DeviceConnectionIndex
 FROM dbo.Device
 $$
 LANGUAGE SQL;
```